# How to update data of table

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Hi I have two tables and I want to update the data of table 2 from table 1 based on the date .

Table 1:

| Id | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8-june-2022 | 2 |
| 1 | 9-june-2022 | 5 |

Table 2:

| Id | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2-june-2022 |  |
| 1 | 6-june-2022 |  |

Table 2 after update:

| Id | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2-june-2022 | 2 |
| 1 | 6-june-2022 | 5 |

The common column is the id and I want to update the data based on id and date.In other words the data should be taken from table 1 in order and update table 2 data also by order

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the `id` - `"Date"` column pairs are unique for throughout the both of the tables, then use a MERGE statement along with an analytic function such as `DENSE_RANK()` as in the following case

```
MERGE INTO table2 t2 
USING (SELECT t1.id AS id1, t1."Date" AS date1, t1.value AS value1,
              t2.id AS id2, t2."Date" AS date2, t2.value AS value2, 
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1."Date") AS rn1,
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.id ORDER BY t2."Date") AS rn2              
         FROM table1 t1
         JOIN table2 t2 
           ON t1.id = t2.id) tt
          ON ( t2.id = tt.id1 AND tt.date2 = t2."Date" AND rn1 = rn2 )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t2.value = tt.value1
```

where I've just replaced the `Date` with `"Date"`. Since **DaTe**(*case insensitive*) is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a column name unless double-quoted.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ktArhbpq)</kbd>